# JSR-303 validations are not working in spring mvc 3.x

Tags: spring-mvc

```
validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar and hibernate-validator-4.1.0.Final.jar are in classpath. 


mvc:annotation-driven is in -servlet.xml file.
```

`@RequestMapping(value = "/addEmployee", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView addEmployee(@Valid EmployeeDTO employeeDTO, 
            BindingResult result) 
            {`

```
   System.out.println("addEmployee employeeDTO! "+ employeeDTO);
       System.out.println("result.getErrorCount()  "+result.getErrorCount());
```

}

`public class EmployeeDTO {`

```
private int employeeId;
public int getEmployeeId() {
    return employeeId;
}


public void setEmployeeId(int employeeId) {
    this.employeeId = employeeId;
}

@NotNull
private String firstName;
@NotNull 
private String lastName;
private Date hireDate;

}
```

```
 in the console

 addEmployee employeeDTO! EmployeeDTO [employeeId=0, firstName=, lastName=, deptName=null, deptId=0, email=, salary=0, jobId=AD_VP, hireDate=null]
result.getErrorCount()  0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DTO doesn't seem to be invalid, according to the console message that you quoted. The `firstName` and `lastName` fields seem to be set as empty strings `""`, not `null`; therefore, there's no reason for the validation to reject your bean.

If you want empty input fields to be bound as null (and rejected by validation), you can register a [StringTrimmerEditor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/propertyeditors/StringTrimmerEditor.html) in your binder.

Comment: now its working.but when combine with custom validations with JSR-303 validations in controller then JSR-303 validations are not working.@InitBinder protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) { binder.registerCustomEditor(String.class, new StringTrimmerEditor(true)); binder.setValidator(new EmailValidator());}